# In firefox,'fadeIn' does not work

Tags: jquery

I have code following:

```
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn();
    //$('body').css("display","block");
});
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    123456
</body>
</html>
```

But,fadeIn does not work, and $('body').css("display","block") works without any issue,what is the problem

Comment: Maybe this is a more viable solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262047/jquery-body-fade-in definitely more browser compatible

Comment: .show() would work, however there is a bug for it with FF. [Link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10227)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the fact that you are setting the css of the HTML body to `display:none;`.  See this example where I just use a div instead of the whole body, and it works in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/T3uX7/2/.

You can see the same code does not work when trying to just fadeIn the `<body>`: http://jsfiddle.net/T3uX7/4/.

To get it to work, just use a `div` to fadeIn and not the whole body.