# Loading pages with php, but fade-in with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, loading, dynamic-loading

Iam loading content in my pages dynamically with php.
I want to add a nice affect like a fade-in with jquery.

But i want my page still working if the user has javascript turn off.

This is my php code to load the content:

```
/// load page content
        $pages_dir = 'content';

        if(!empty($_GET['p'])) {

            $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
            //delete . and ..
            unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

            $p = $_GET['p'];

            // only files that are in the array can be loaded
            if (in_array($p. '.php', $pages)) {
                include($pages_dir. '/'.$p. '.php');    

            } else {
                echo 'This page is not available';
            }
        } else {
            include($pages_dir. '/index.php');
        }
```

Comment: Your PHP code isn't relevant here; can you show us your jQuery code instead?

Comment: So, the fade-in happens on the client, which has ZERO to do with PHP.

Comment: Pages/sites which force me to sit through a pointless fade-in effect are sites I will never visit again. Gimme my data/info NOW, and don't waste my time with useless visuals.

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262047/jquery-body-fade-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262047/jquery-body-fade-in)

Comment: @MarcB While I agree, we're not really a [usability site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) ;) We're just here to beat the daylights out of technical issues programmers face.

Comment: @MarcB Even my aunt hates it.... just got the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i did. wrapped a div around my PHP code with id "fadein" and then used this jquery code:

```
$(function(){
            $('#fadein').hide();
            $('#fadein').fadeIn();

        });
```

Easy